# Java media control ala Youtube

Tags: java, youtube, controls, media

I'm looking to write a Java control that acts like the media control on youtube. It should have a download progress, current playback state and let the user scrub around on the video. Has anyone done this in Java or will I need to roll this myself?

Comment: I am just a bit curious: Why do you want it to do with Java?

Comment: It needs to run on OSX/Linux/Windows/Andriod and we already have a lot of it working in a Java project.

Answer (score 1):

You can try JavaFx. Take a look [here](http://blogs.oracle.com/rakeshmenonp/entry/javafx_youtube)

Comment: While your answer is reasonable right now, please add a bit more detail. You answer will be useless the day the link is dead, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Answer (score 0):

I found a decent GPL one in the Cortado video player java applet. http://www.flumotion.net/cortado/